# Objective-C: Type signature of blocks with block return types

Tags: objective-c, nested, block

I'm having trouble writing a nested block. Say I want a block that takes and integer. That block returns a block that takes another integer, and returns the sum of the two integers. I haven't had any luck writing this out. Here's one try, which is no worse than any other of mine:

```
(int ^(int)) (^bblock)(int) = ^(int a) {
    return ^(int b){ return a + b; };
};
```

Can anybody spot what's wrong?

Comment: `typedef` is your friend.

Comment: @CarlNorum Or Haskell. :P

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare+foo+as+block+%28int%29+returning+block+%28int%29+returning+int

Comment: Make sure that you are returning a block copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite ugly, but you can do it using parenthesis instead of typedefs:

```
int (^(^functor)(int))(int) = ^(int a) {
    return Block_copy(^(int b) {
        return a + b;
    });
};
```

Comment: I think you meant `(int)`, not `(int, int)`

Comment: Read your block again. The inner block should only take `b`, and it should capture `a` from the outer block.

Comment: For the record, the `Block_copy()` should only be necessary under MRR. ARC should copy it for you. Also, unless you're writing pure C, it's preferable to use `-copy` instead of `Block_copy()`.

Comment: @KevinBallard That should be right as well - I don't know since I don't use ARC.

Comment: @KevinBallard (And I have saved my test file as block.c, hence `Block_copy()`.)

Comment: @mattjgalloway Run your `NSRunLoop` fast before I catch you :P Seriously: for me, ARC is ugly and foreign in a C-based language. Let's say I'm used to MRC and I don't make memory management mistakes.

Comment: @H2CO3 - You're missing out on some neat optimisations then that the compiler & runtime can make. Check out my blog for more details.

Comment: Great. Okay, now, how about a block returning a block which takes multiple parameters?

Comment: @JakeBromberg just comma-separate the arguments.